# Overlay button img in html with jquery

Tags: html, css, overlay

I having a problem with overlaying an bootstrap glyphicon image over a background img, and have it clickable as a button.

I'm also using a jquery template style for the rest of the pages that I want to show, like flipboard style pages.

Here is the html code, the problem is the last code snippet

```
<body>
    <div id="st-container" class="st-container">
        <div class="st-pusher">
        <nav class="st-menu st-effect" id="menu">
           <img src="" style="height:50px;" alt="" />
            <ul id="url-list"></ul>
        </nav>

        <script id="pageTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            <div class="${theClass}" style="${theStyle}">
                <div class="front">
                    <div class="outer">
                        <div class="content" style="${theContentStyleFront}">
                            <div class="inner">{{html theContentFront}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <div class="outer">
                        <div class="content" style="${theContentStyleBack}">
                            <div class="inner">{{html theContentBack}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
```

Here is the trouble code - if I remove the style="float:left" the button is clickable - the problem then is that my front and back pages are not overlayed, if add the style="float:left" then button is not clickable, on the other hand the img is overlayed with the front and back page.

```
<div id="st-trigger-effects" style="float:left;">
    <button type="button" data-effect="st-effect" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I tired another variation

```
<div id="st-trigger-effects" class="imgoverlay">
    <button type="button" data-effect="st-effect" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The css is for the body

```
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed','Arial Narrow', serif;
    background: #ddd url(../img/background.jpg) repeat top left;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and the overlay class in css

```
imgoverlay{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Not sure were I go wrong here, I still learning the css/html

Comment: Can you post fiddle of this?

Answer (score 0):

Missing the dot that indicates the `imgoverlay` is a css class.

```
.imgoverlay {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Without the dot, the browser looks for tag named `imgoverlay`.
With the dot, the browser looks for any element that have class `imgoverlay`.

Comment: That solve the issue with the overlay, it show correctly - still an issue with that the button I have is not clickable when I use the imgoverlay -                                                                <div id="st-trigger-effects" class="imgoverlay">                     <button type="button" data-effect="st-effect" class="btn btn-default">     if i remove the calss="imgoverlay" then the button is clickable